# Limit number of UICollectionView with dynamic sized cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a view which displays the music interests that a user has.  Since the text of each interest can be different in length, I have used a UICollectionView to render these items.

[image]

The problem is that I would like to limit the size of the list to just 7 lines.  If there is more items than can fit, I need to show an item [...] at the end to indicate that there is more items.

In the example above, I would change the word "Grimes" for "...".

Is there any way, with dynamic sized UICollectionView cells, to know HOW MANY items fit into the given space, before it gets rendered on the screen, and thus be able to change the last item to "..." (either by removing the extra items and adding a new one, or by updating the last cell title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also handle it after the fact by allowing the collectionview to lay itself out and determine it's last cell, then grab the last cell in the collectionView's .visibleCells array.

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    UICollectionViewCell *targetCell = self.collectionView.visibleCells.lastObject;
    targetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];//or whatever needs to change
}];
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, but visibleCells is not ordered, so you need to parse for the last cell.

Comment: E.g. `[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } completion:^(BOOL success){
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] mutableCopy];
        [indexPaths sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] ;
        UICollectionViewCell * cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[indexPaths lastObject]];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }];`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have a method to calculate the dimension of each item.  It's not that hard to implement this behavior by yourself.

You need a method to estimate the size (or rows) needs for a list of items.  Something like:

```
func preProcessList(originalList: [Item]) -> (displayList: [Item], needThreeDots: Bool)
```